# google drive upload php

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

```
require_once ('../google-api-php/vendor/autoload.php');


$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) &&         $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName(uniqid().'.jpg');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

$data = file_get_contents('a.jpg');

$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
      'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    ));

print_r($createdFile);

} else {
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
exit();
```

this is the error :

`Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }.....`

But the client id and client secret ara copyfrom my console ...

Comment: That means there is a problem with your access token. It could be null, damaged or expired. Trace the http request and look at the Authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

Now the script work, 2 answer :

1:how can i create a folder on drive if the folder not exist?

2:how can i set a folder to insert the uploaded file .

tanks

Answer (score 0):

The script work but when the session expired or change web browser i must insert my google credential , is it a way to work without insert credential?